# El modulo solicitado "No proporciona una exportacion predeterminada" JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto, javascript-import, three.js

Buen dìa.
Este es el error que me da por consola el navegador web.Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../basic/KeyCode.js' does not provide an export named 'default' (at linea 1).

Aquì esta alguna parte de mi codigo, donde esta la linea de error.

KeyController.js

```
import keyCode from "../basic/KeyCode.js"
import keyListener from "../basic/keyListener.js"

const keyController = new KeyController()

export default keyController

export { KeyController }
```

Index.js

```
import camera from './basic/Camera.js';
import light from './basic/Light.js';
import renderer from './basic/Renderer.js';
import scene from './basic/Scene.js';
import resize from './basic/Resize.js';
import cube from './basic/shapes/Cube.js';
import plane from './basic/shapes/Plane.js'
import loopMachine from './basic/LoopMachine.js';
import keyListener from './basic/keyListener.js';
import { keyCode } from './basic/KeyCode.js';
import characterController from './controller/CharacterController.js';
import keyController from './controller/KeyController.js';
import moveController from './controller/MoveController.js';

scene.add(cube);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(plane);

camera.position.set(2,2,-2);

characterController.addCharacter(cube)
characterController.addController(keyController)
characterController.addController(moveController)

loopMachine.addCallback(() => {
    camera.lookAt(cube.position);
    if(keyListener.isPressed(keyCode.ENTER)) cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);    
});

resize.start(renderer);
loopMachine.start();
keyListener.start();
characterController.start()
```